# docker invalid tag format

Tags: docker, docker-compose, format, tags

I'm using docker-compose to deploy an application stack and on some of the systems, I'm facing a strange issue ( not all deployments are showing this error , happening only on some )

I'm using ENV-File for tags and when I try to PULL these images, I'm getting error something like below

```
docker-compose --env-file /path/to/version.env -f /home/user/Desktop/sds/docker-compose-app.yml pull 
ERROR: for app  invalid tag format


invalid tag format
```

inside the docker-compose-app.yml

```
version: "2.4"
services:
  app:
    image: my.privaterepo.com:3747/app-channel-manager:${app}
    init: true
    #cpu_shares: 73
    pids_limit: -1
    ports:
      - 8451:8443
    env_file:
      - /var/lib/app/app.env
      - /var/lib/app/common.env
    healthcheck:
      test: "curl -fsk https://localhost:8443/api/SystemInfo || exit 1"
      interval: 1m30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10
    networks:
      - app-network
networks:
  app-network:
    external: true
```

my `version.env` is

```
app="12.0.5-rc1-R.1.1.1"
```

any Idea , what is causing these `invalid tag format` errors;

I have had given a try to execute with --debug enabled

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem that it was due to the `"` because they're part of the value.

You can debug the issue with `docker-compose -v`.

Here is an extract from the documentation:

> There is no special handling of quotation marks. This means that they are part of the VAL.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/#syntax-rules